# Unable to Print the full content of Page when horizontal scroll bar appears

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net

I need to print the current page in the asp.net application for that I am using `javascript:window.print()`.

It's working fine when the page content is within the bounds. However, if the horizontal scrollbar appears as a result of overflow, am able to print only the visible content while the overflown contents couldn't be printed.

Is there any workaround to get this working? Is there any other alternative apart from javascript to achieve this functionality?

Answer (score 0):

you can continue using javascript. however, try embedding this in the `<head>` section of your markup:

```
<style type="text/css" media="print">
    #yourDivIdHere{width: 90%; overflow:auto;}
</style>
```

hope that works!